# Alert Window - TakeScreenshot - Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I know the code to get the browser screenshot during a failure in Selenium C#.

```
ITakesScreenshot ssdriver = gnr._driver as ITakesScreenshot;
Screenshot screenshot = ssdriver.GetScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile(saveLocation, ImageFormat.Png);
```

In our application currrently, an unhandled alert pop up exception is being displayed sometimes during form submission. During that scenario, the above code for screenshot fails at step2. Is there a way to take complete screenshot of the browser with alert pop up?
I know Selenium is limited to browser only , the other day there was failure on "File Upload", but the screenshot was of the browser upload form only, the windows File Upload pop up is not displayed in screenshot.

Comment: This is an application bug. Selenium isn't going to fix your application.

Comment: I am aware,its application bug. Just wanted to know if there is code to take a screenshot. So why Down Vote for that. Anyways, I can do something like below solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose your code into try Catch blocks. If your code fails to take a snapshot because of the alert, it will jump to catch block where you can use

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

And after that take the screen shot again.

Comment: Thanks for workaround. Key was to include Assert.Fail & above code in the catch block-to understand the failure due to UnExpected Alert.